# Как из одной ячейки tableView перейти в другой контроллер?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, apple, мобильная-разработка

Я делаю проект где нужно использовать tableView по категориям.Например список предметов биология, математика, история ,физика , англиский.Я нажимаю на одну категорию (к примеру на математику) и получаю доступ к информации по математике.Мой вопрос состоит в том как сделать переход с ячейки одного tableView на другой контроллер или что то еще.Что для этого нужно ипользовоть как-то прописать в коде?Какие есть способы?Если что то не понятно в вопросе напишите попытаюсь сказать понятней.Прошу ответ на swift.Я искал в интернете ничего точного нету.Прошу написать развёрнутый объект.

Comment: Вот очень хороший пример: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/CreateATableView.html

Comment: Приведите пример кода что у Вас есть, как делаете, что не получается.

Answer (score 1):

Есть два варианта: можно использовать отдельный View для каждого из параметров (столько view, сколько предметов), либо один, но менять значение какой-либо переменной на контроллере назначения.

Для перехода по нажатию на ячейку используйте функцию:

```
// устанавливаем действие при выделении ячейки
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
// выполняем переход. в качестве sender-аргумента советую отправить IndexPath ячейки, откуда отправляете
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "ID сеги (перехода)", sender: indexPath)
}
// после этого осуществляете подготовку к переходу на контроллер
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

// Проверяем идентификатор сеги
    switch segue.identifier! {
        case "ID сеги (перехода)":
        let dvc = segue.destination as! SelectOptionTableViewController // Это имя контроллера View, на который осуществляется переход

// в моём случае определена переменна на segue.destination под именем airportID: Airport (подкласс CoreData), как я написал делать не стоит - дурная практика передавать объект CoreData не по id объекта

        dvc.airportID = self.frc.object(at: sender as! IndexPath).objectID
    default:
        break
    }
}
```